# Creating a batch script to remove a column from txt file

Tags: batch-file, automation, csv

I have a text file that has columns delimited using a pipe character ("|").
The csv has hundreds of columns, and I only want to keep the first 254 columns.
How do i create a batch script that will create a new output.txt file with only the columns i am requesting?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.csv) do (
   set "input=%%a"
   set "output="
   for /L %%b in (1,1,254) do (
      for /F "tokens=1* delims=|" %%c in ("!input!") do (
         set "output=!output!|%%c"
         set "input=%%d"
      )
   )
   echo !output:~1!
)) > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

And a batch / jscript hybrid scripting solution. If saved as `split.cmd`, call with

`type inputfile.txt | split.cmd "|" 254 > outputfile.txt`

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************
    setlocal enableextensions

    rem arguments : delimiter numberOfColumns

    set "delimiter=%~1"
    if not defined delimiter set "delimiter=,"

    set "columns=%~2"
    if not defined columns set "columns=10000"

    cscript //nologo //e:Javascript "%~f0" 

    endlocal
    exit /b

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************
    var IN  = WScript.StdIn, 
        OUT = WScript.StdOut;
    var shell       = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"),
        delimiter   = shell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("delimiter"), 
        columns     = shell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("columns") ; 

    while ( ! IN.AtEndOfStream ){
        OUT.WriteLine(IN.ReadLine().split(delimiter).slice(0,columns).join(delimiter));
    };
```